# Manage state in react js when loosing input focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next scenario in my react js appplication:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const inputDefautValues = ["first val", "second value"];

const Input = ({ setIsopen, val }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(val);
  }, [val]);
  return (
    <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setIsopen(e.target.value === "?");
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      onBlur={(e) => e.target.value === "?" && setValue(val)}
    />
  );
};

const Modal = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Modal data: <input />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsopen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {inputDefautValues.map((val, i) => (
        <Input val={val} key={i} setIsopen={setIsopen} />
      ))}
      {isOpen && <Modal />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The idea is next: User type `?` in one of the input and then typing something in the second one the previous value should return and `?` dissapears (the flow is working at the moment). If user type `?` in one of the input also a modal window appears, but clicking on the input from that modal also restore the initial value of the input making `?` to dissapear. The expected behaviour is when user type `?` and then click on the modal input the `?` sign should stay in the first input, if user type `?` in one of these 2 inputs ant then click on next input the `?` sign should dissapear and initial value should appear (like is now).
 Question: How to prevent input to remove `?` sing when clicking on the modal input taking into account the scenario above?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/loving-tereshkova-fsc7lz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Comment: add the sandbox again please.

Comment: @warmachine https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dark-star-4rg3y8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js Does it work?

Comment: nope, i think you need to make it public, create sandbox and check in your incognito mode whether you can access it or not.

Comment: @warmachine, https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/loving-tereshkova-fsc7lz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js does it work?

Comment: yes working let me check the issue, few mins

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/loving-tereshkova-forked-h9gv7l?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A15%2C33

check this now, is this the behaviour you need?

Comment: @warmachine, 1. When user type ? in one of the input and then  click on the next input the initial value of the previous inut should be restored. 2. Id user type ? in the input and then modal opens, click on the modal input, the ? sign should stay  there (oposite to fisrt scenario). Now the ? sign is not removed  in any case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256780/discussion-between-asking-and-warmachine).

Comment: @warmachine, did you get the idea?

Comment: At the moment, when you type `?` into one input and then click on another, the `?` goes back to the original value and the modal stays open, is that expected behaviour as well (that the modal stays open even though there isn't a `?`)?

Comment: @NickParsons, the modal should be opened only if in the input is `?`

Answer (score 1):

Given the... rather odd interaction, I recommend using a custom event to get the expected behavior.

A couple changes we could make to the existing code would take place in your `Input` component. We'll be making the following changes:

- change `onBlur` -> `onFocus`
- keep track of the initial value using another `useState` declaration
- `useRef` to keep track of the input element reference

The code would then look like so:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const inputDefautValues = ["first val", "second value"];

const Input = ({ setIsopen, val }) => {
  // keep a reference to the input
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [initialValue, setInitialValue] = useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  // keep track of the initial value so we can handle a custom revert action
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!inputRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const revertHandler = () => {
      // only listen to the revert event if the value is '?'
      if (inputRef.current?.value !== "?") {
        return;
      }

      // when event fires, revert back to the original value
      setValue(initialValue);
      // close the modal
      setIsopen(false);
    };

    // this is a custom event that will be fired
    inputRef.current.addEventListener("revert", revertHandler);
    return () => {
      inputRef.current.removeEventListener("revert", revertHandler);
    };
  }, [initialValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // store the initialValue
    setInitialValue(val);
    setValue(val);
  }, [val]);

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    // when the input is focused, fire a custom event if the relatedTarget is an input
    // only your `Input` component `<input />` will have the custom revert handler
    if (e.relatedTarget instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      e.relatedTarget.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent("revert", {
          composed: true,
        })
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setIsopen(e.target.value === "?");
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      onFocus={handleFocus}
    />
  );
};

...
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/loving-tereshkova-forked-4s282t)

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any additional questions/concerns.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried delayed the execution of the onBlur handler using setTimeout?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const inputDefautValues = ["first val", "second value"];

const Input = ({ setIsOpen, val, modalInputRef }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(val);
  }, [val]);

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Check if the currently focused element is the modal input
      if (document.activeElement !== modalInputRef.current) {
        if (e.target.value === "?") {
          setValue(val);
        }
      }
    }, 0); // Delay to allow the document to update the activeElement
  };

  return (
    <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setIsOpen(e.target.value === "?");
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
  );
};

const Modal = ({ modalInputRef }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Modal data: <input ref={modalInputRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const modalInputRef = useState(useRef(null))[0]; // Using useRef to reference the modal input

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {inputDefautValues.map((val, i) => (
        <Input val={val} key={i} setIsOpen={setIsOpen} modalInputRef={modalInputRef} />
      ))}
      {isOpen && <Modal modalInputRef={modalInputRef} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it does not work. I need when i switch inputs from the top to restore value, but when i click on the input from modal to leave `?` sign.

Comment: To ensure the "?" sign remains when clicking on the modal input but restores the initial value when switching between the top inputs, you can modify the approach slightly. The main idea is to use a combination of states and event handling to more accurately control when to restore the initial value and when to leave the "?" sign as is.

Comment: i tryed a lot of things, could you help me with that?